# How to change symbols to sympy subs in the np.array?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I try to use sympy symbols which is in the np.array matrix.
but, it doesn't work. How to fix my cord?

```py
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, solve
dna_list = np.random.rand(10,2) 
data_list = np.random.rand(10,3)
alpha=np.sqrt([2])
x1 = dna_list[:,0]
x2 = dna_list[:,1]
m = data_list[:,1]
b = data_list[:,2]

RSMX= np.array([[6, 15*alpha, 1], [-2, 15, 1], [10, 15, 1], [-alpha*1, 10, 1], [6, 10, 1], [10*alpha, 10, 1], [-2, -5, 1], [10, -5, 1], [6, -alpha*5, 1]])

print(RSMX)
```

```py
xhat1, xhat2 = symbols('xhat1, xhat2')

RSMy = (m)/(1-xhat1)+(m)/(1-xhat2)+(b)
print(RSMy)

SOLVE = RSMy.subs({xhat1:6, xhat2:15+alpha})
```

---

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 SOLVE = RSMy.subs({xhat1:6, xhat2:15+alpha})
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'subs'

Answer (score 0):

`RSMy` you are using is the `numpy` array and has no `subs` method. You should apply `subs` method for every element inside this array. You can do it this way:

`SOLVE = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.subs({xhat1:6, xhat2:15+alpha}))(RSMy)`

Also note that you are using `alpha=np.sqrt([2])` that returns you an array, not a number. I recommend you to use `alpha=np.sqrt(2)`, it can be critical in some cases.